# A polling method and nested loop performance issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr

**Development Environment**

- Entity Framework 6
- ASP.NET MVC5
- SignalR for bidirectional communication with IIS8.5

---

**Simple Explanation**

There are 12 gates. Using our face recognition system, we check every person who tries to enter each gates. My MVC web application is to show the result data to the gate-keeper. And this is the **important part.** The people in the control center look closely at the current situations in real time. **Put it simply, *Always Two Connections For A gate*.**

---

**Simple Flow**

1. Face recognition completed
2. The recognition server is going to change a flag on a database
3. My polling job will catch that change within 0.3 seconds
4. Send the result data to the clients

---

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(300);

    using (DisplayModel DPModel = new DisplayModel(NameOrConnstring))
    {
        // Get the result data if there are any flag changes.
        var ResultData = DPModel.GateDisplay
                         .Where(x => x.g_flag != false)
                         .Select(x => new { x.a_acu_data_id, x.g_status }).ToList();

        // If no result data was received and no observers were found ( gate connections ), skip this polling.
        if (ResultData.Count > 0 && Observers.Count > 0)
        {
            // the first loop for each gates.
            foreach (var Gatedata in ResultData)
            {
                string GateName = Gatedata.a_acu_data_id;

                // See if a client has this current gate ID
                if (Observers.ContainsKey(GateName))
                {
                    // Get the result data produced by the face recognition server
                    GateViewDataModel ProcessedData = DPModel.DisplayViewData
                            .Where(x => x.GATE_NUM == GateName)
                            .Select(x => new GateViewDataModel
                            {
                                COMPANY_NAME = x.COMPANY_NAME,
                                NAME = x.NAME,
                                ENRO_IMG = x.ENRO_IMG,
                                GATE_NUM = x.GATE_NUM,
                                LOG_IMG = x.LOG_IMG,
                                G_STATUS = x.G_STATUS,
                                MODE = x.MODE,
                                PERMIT_AREA = x.PERMIT_AREA
                            }).ToList<GateViewDataModel>().First();

                    if (ProcessedData.ENRO_IMG != null && ProcessedData.ENRO_IMG.Length > 0) ProcessedData.CONVERTED_ENRO_IMAGE = Convert.ToBase64String(enc.Decrypt(ProcessedData.ENRO_IMG, key));
                    if (ProcessedData.LOG_IMG != null && ProcessedData.LOG_IMG.Length > 0) ProcessedData.CONVERTED_LOG_IMG = Convert.ToBase64String(enc.Decrypt(ProcessedData.LOG_IMG, key));

                    // No need to send the original binary data.
                    ProcessedData.ENRO_IMG = new byte[] { 0 };
                    ProcessedData.LOG_IMG = new byte[] { 0 };

                    // the second, nested loop for all the connections to this current gate.
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>> dic in Observers[GateName])
                    {
                        // Server sent event by SignalR
                        dic.Value.Caller.onReceived(GateName, ProcessedData);
                    }

                    // Initilaize the flag.
                    var Entity = DPModel.GateDisplay.Single(x => x.a_acu_data_id == GateName);
                    if (Entity != null)
                    {
                        Entity.g_flag = false;
                        DPModel.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is set to run forever right after my application startup.

**What I just can't change is**

The way I receive the result data. It would be ideal if the face recognition server could send the data directly to the each clients everytime it finishes the recognition job. But unfortunately, it doesn't and I don't have enough time to change that right now. ( *I hate the former server developer... :[* )

**Performance**

When my polling catches all the changes at once ( *this will rarely happen though...* ), there's going to be 12 loops with two nested loops ( *Two clients are supposed to get the data, one is for the gate-keeper and another is for the people in control center* ). It takes about 0.8s or 1.8s to complete distribution of the result data to each clients.

**This is O(n2),** isn't it? I feel like I'm really stupid... any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `ToList<GateViewDataModel>().First();` instead of just `.First()`?

Comment: @NateDiamond I made a mistake there. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: In fact, if you just need the first, you should be doing .Where().First(), then making the object based on that. You're iterating over the whole list and making a bunch of objects when it seems like you just need the one.

Comment: @NateDiamond I've tried it, but casting should be done, which I couldn't. How can I select an entity and bind it to `GateViewDataModel` without declaring new {}?

Comment: `x` has some type, right? If you can't make a constructor for `GateViewDataModel` which accepts that type, then you can make a helper method: `public static GateViewDataModel ConvertViewDataToViewModel(XType x);` Which does that exact code (returns a new `GateViewDataModel`, filling it with the provided data). Then you just say `GateViewDataModel ProcessedData = ConvertViewDataToViewModel(DPModel.DisplayViewData.First(x => x.GATE_NUM == GateName));` Just note that `First` will throw an exception if one isn't there, but you seem to be handling that anyway.